I'm using Alchemy for an airdrop, but after completing airdrop, my confirmTransaction function is not working, which prevents below code from running
    try {
          let signature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
            new PublicKey(publicKey),
            LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
          );
    
          console.log("Airdrop complete");  
          await connection.confirmTransaction({
             signature,
          });
            
        // **code is not reaching here**
        const balance = await connection.getBalance(new PublicKey(publicKey));
            
        const balanceInSOL = balance / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
            
        console.log(`Balance of wallet ${publicKey} is: ${balanceInSOL} SOL`);
   } catch (error) {
      console.error("An error occurred:", error);
   }


what is the logged error ?

This works on my side, so perhaps you've gone over the airdrop limit for that key -- it's typically limited to 1-2 SOL per day.
Or you may be using finalized confirmation with your connection, which takes ~13 seconds to confirm, in which case you'll need to wait longer or change the confirmation level to confirmed.

confirmTransaction has recently been removed from RPCs on devnet. That's why it fails on the line connection.confirmTransaction()

Where did you get that information? confirmTransaction isn't an RPC call

i had it here : https://x.com/rexstjohn/status/1825579049680581017
are you sure that connection.xxxxx isn't always an rpc call ?

or may be connection.confirmTransaction is not an rpc endpoint, but uses a deprecated (and now removed) rpc endpoint in the background ?

Oh wow, I didn't realize these were ever RPC calls! Considering they were deprecated in April 2020, I don't think your web3.js is using them: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/9309
